# Sequence within a partition in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been looking around for 2 days and have not been able to figure out this one. Using dataset below and SQL server 2016 I would like to get the row number of each row by 'id' and 'cat' ordered by 'date' in asc order but would like to see a reset of the sequence if a different value in the 'cat' column for the same 'id' is found(see rows in green). Any help would be appreciated.

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  The simplest solution in this case is probably a difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, cat, seqnum - seqnum_c order by date) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, cat order by date) as seqnum_c
      from t
     ) t;
```

Why this works is a bit tricky to explain.  But, if you look at the sequence numbers in the subquery, you'll see that the difference defines the groups you want to define.

Note:  This assumes that the `date` column provides a *stable* sort.  You seem to have duplicates in the column.  If there really are duplicates and you have no secondary column for sorting, then try `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!! It worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: As an attempt at a little bit of insight as to the "why this works", I tend to think of it as "if you have two contiguous sequences increasing at the same rate, the difference between them will be the same for items in the same group and will change at boundaries".

Comment: @BenThul . . . I explain it that way sometimes.  I still think that just seeing the results is a faster way to convince people.

Comment: Wow o_0 
So cool trick, really 'expand the horizons'
Many thanks!